# How to extract Heading tags in PHP from a string?

Tags: php, text-extraction, domparser

From a string that contains a lot of HTML, how can I extract all the text from `<h1><h2>etc` tags into a new variable?

I would like to capture all of the text from these elements and store them in a new variable as comma-delimited values.

Is it possible using `preg_match_all()`?

Comment: When the question is "How do I extract stuff from HTML", the answer is NEVER to use regular expressions. Instead, see the discussion on [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php).

Comment: i wished there was an answere here with php built-in functions like substring and the like. hate these regexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to use regular expressions, I think that:

```
preg_match_all('/<h[0-6]>([^</h[0-6]>*)</h/i', $string, $matches);
```

should work as long as your header tags are not nested. As others have said, if you're not in control of the HTML, regular expressions are not a great way to do this.

Comment: This will fail in a LOT of likely cases -- like when the heading tags have attributes.  This is not a robust or reliable solution.  A legitimate DOM parser should be used on valid HTML.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to clean up the HTML ($html_str in the example) with tidy:

```
$tidy_config = array(
    "indent"               => true,
    "output-xml"           => true,
    "output-xhtml"         => false,
    "drop-empty-paras"     => false,
    "hide-comments"        => true,
    "numeric-entities"     => true,
    "doctype"              => "omit",
    "char-encoding"        => "utf8",
    "repeated-attributes"  => "keep-last"
);

$xml_str = tidy_repair_string($html_str, $tidy_config);
```

Then you can load the XML ($xml_str) into a DOMDocument:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_str);
```

And finally you can use Horia Dragomir's method:

```
$list = $doc->getElementsByTagName("h1");
for ($i = 0; $i < $list->length; $i++) {
    print($list->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>\n");
}
```

Or you could also use XPath for more complex queries on the DOMDocument (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$list = $xpath->evaluate("//h1");
```

Comment: something broken about this script, try it with simple HTML like '<html><body><h1>Test</h1><br></body></html>'

Comment: What error do you get? If I try the example you give it works as expected and prints "Test"

Comment: as in all of that code above with the only change being: $xml_str = tidy_repair_string('<html><body><h1>Test</h1><br></body></html>', $tidy_config); ??? It breaks my script, there is an error in there that is crashing like a typo or something

Comment: I guess that the 'tidy' module is not enabled in you're php.ini.
If you're using xampp (or some other AMP) uncomment the line "extension=php_tidy.dll"
If you're using Ubuntu use "apt-get install php5-tidy" to install and enable it.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better of using an HTML parser. But for really simple scenarios, something like this might do:

```
if (preg_match_all('/<h\d>([^<]*)<\/h\d>/iU', $str, $matches)) {
    // $matches contains all instances of h1-h6
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a super old post, however I wanted to mention the best way I was able to collectively grab heading tags.

```
<h1>title</h1> and <h2>title 2</h2>
```

This method (works as a regex, however PHP acts a bit differently.)

```
/<\s*h[1-2](?:.*)>(.*)</\s*h/i
```

**use this in your preg_match**

```
|<\s*h[1-2](?:.*)>(.*)</\s*h|Ui
```

`$group[1]` will include what ever is in between the heading tag. 
 `$group[0]` is everything `<h1>test</h`

This will account for spaces, and if someone adds "class/id"

```
<h1 class="classname">test</h1>
```

the class/id (group) is ignored.

**NOTE**: When I analyze HTML tags, I always strip out and replace all White space, line breaks, tabs etc.. with a 1 space. This minimizes multi-lines, dotalls... And very large amounts of white space which in some cases can mess with regex formatting.

- of course I am only grabbing 1-2 heading tags, change that to 0-9 to grab all.
- If anyone else has a mod to add or a fix to my code, please respond, I'd really like to know.
- On the contrary with Regex being bad with HTML, that is a very open argument. Because if you design your php functions, and regex expressions to perfectly strip away the junk and prepare the html for regex specific expressions, You will be perfectly able to grab what you are looking for. You can make enough regex functions to replace amateur html work.

Here is a link to the test page [regex test](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=1300)

Comment: I think you meant `|<\s*h[1-2](?:.*)>(.*)</\s*h[1-2]>|Ui` otherwise it won't grab the whole element and cuts off the closing tag>
Also note this won't match if there's line breaks (`<br/>`) in the heading which is entirely possible if working with user generated content

Comment: No one should be implementing this advice in their own application if the input is valid HTML.  Always use a legitimate DOM parser until a DOM parser does not provide the desired result.  I love regex (a lot), but there is a time and place for it -- this is not the time nor the place.  Here are just a couple of ways that this regex answer will fail: https://3v4l.org/LXXSQ  Make no mistake, "Regex is DOM-ignorant".  IOW, it has no idea whether it is matching with substrings that ARE DOM elements or just SEEM like DOM elements based on the pattern design.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah this is a really old post. There are better ways to do this today, however, I have scanned over 5 million web pages using this simple regex technology, and has not failed. I would say the majority of pages are actually valid enough to use a regex. Possibly these issues will occur on low-level pages. But yes, if you want to be safe, use php's built-in methods for extracting HTML elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended not to use regex for this job and use something [SimpleHTMLDOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I have found regexp to be better at this. DOM parser is somewhat unreliable on web pages that have broken HTML or invalid HTML structures.

Comment: @datasn.io Until you can definitely determine that the incoming document contains invalid/broken html, your default parsing choice should be a DOM parser and not regex.  Only use regex when a legitimate parser fails to serve your needs.

Comment: @codaddict this is not a very generous answer.

Answer (score 2):

please also consider the native [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) php class.

You can use `$domdoc->getElementsByTagName('h1')` to get your headings.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share my solution:

```
function get_all_headings( $content ) {
    preg_match_all( '/\<(h[1-6])\>(.*)<\/h[1-6]>/i', $content, $matches );

    $r = array();
    if( !empty( $matches[1] ) && !empty( $matches[2] ) ){
        $tags = $matches[1];
        $titles = $matches[2];
        foreach ($tags as $i => $tag) {
            $r[] = array( 'tag' => $tag, 'title' => $titles[ $i ] );
        }
    }

    return $r;
}
```

This function will return an empty array if headings were not found or something like this:

```
array (
    array (
        'tag' => 'h1',
        'title' => 'This is a title',
    ),
    array (
        'tag' => 'h2',
        'title' => 'This is the second title',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an old questions, since there is no newer answers. i wrote this with php built in dom parser.

```
$dom -> loadHTML("your html string here..");
$h2s = $dom -> getElementsByTagName('h2');

foreach ( $h2s as $h2 )
{
  echo $h2 -> nodeValue;
}
```